# How to change picture element srcset value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, srcset, picturefill

How does one target the srcset property of the source tag within a picture element with jQuery?  What is the correct jQuery code to change the value of xxxxxxxxxx.jpg and yyyyyyyyyy.jpg below?

```
<picture>
    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="/images/bannerAds/xxxxxxxxxx.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/bannerAds/yyyyyyyyyy.jpg">
    <source srcset="/images/bannerAds/zzzz_320x50.png">
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAADs=" alt="Clio">
</picture>
```

Comment: same way you would change any other element attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Well there are many ways to get it done. And honestly, someone's correct approach may not be the correct one for you due to various reasons.

This is an approach.

```
function replace_srcset(target, replacement)
{
    // Search for the target
    $('source[srcset="'+target+'"]').attr('srcset', replacement);
}

replace_srcset('/images/bannerAds/xxxxxxxxxx.jpg', '/images/bannerAds/somethingelse.jpg');
```

Comment: Changed target for element but it does what it should thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the `src` then you want to overwrite all the `source`s. Just remove them since you're not using them:

```
$('picture source').remove();
```

And then set the `src` normally:

```
$('img').attr('src', 'your-new-image.jpg');
```

If you want to use multiple `src` by keeping it responsive, then use Stephanus' code multiple times.